# Design Pattern for send email application running periodically?

Tags: linux, django, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am working on a feature that will allow the user to configure an email to be sent a time he chooses. 
Once an user has saved his configuration, an email will be sent daily at configured time, until he deactivates or deletes that configuration. There can be many configurations with different times.

So far I was doing something like this:

- Run a cron job every 10 minutes.
- Look for email configurations that are to be executed in (now - 10 minutes).
- Send those emails and update status logs.

This used to work fine but has few pitfalls:

Emails configured at intersection times like 02:00 were not sent sometimes. Due to a deployment or high CPU usage, cron didn't run at all.

In both scenarios, email that are missed won't be picked again in next 24 hours.

**How should I go forward to design a robust system that guarantees that all emails are sent?**

If it matters I'm using Django and a linux machine.

Comment: did you take a look on [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html)? They have a [periodic tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules).

Comment: @ClaudioSantos Still it'll have the same problem as crons no?

Comment: the mainly difference is tasks will be managed by a task queue, so you know what task failed or not. [Task retry](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-retry)

Comment: How about "at" integrated with cron.daily? So put all the settings in a configuration file and then action batch job queuing from cron.daily.

Answer (score 0):

The next step in you solution is to control who failed or not, but you're going to reinvent the wheel

So, your problem have a Solution Pattern called Task Queue. It's an application that manage the life cycle of tasks and allow you to:

- keep track of what tasks are running or failed;
- retry tasks;
- manage taks priorities;
- manage the execution flow;
- create different queues for each subject;

Through a task queue you separate the application that manage tasks from the application that execute those tasks.

Using celery you could have a light machine running redis called broker, and another one running your tasks, called worker.

Take a look in the [first steps](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps), Celery will be your champion!!!